# What is the correct way to "stop / shutdown" a QNetworkAccessManager?

Tags: qt, access-violation, qnetworkaccessmanager, qt5.5

I have a `QNetworkAccessManager` . Let's assume I have a pending request:

```
QNetworkRequest request(url);
this->m_networkManager->get(request)
```

Can I shutdown the `QNetworkAccessManager` at any time?  I am asking because I see a `write access violation` when I destruct my object `m_networkManager` during a pending get request.

Or how can I safely destroy the manager, there seems to be no stop or shutdown functionality.

Comment: Did you try calling `abort()` on the `QNetworkReply` that is returned from `QNetworkManager::get()`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. One of the workarounds I have in mind, but it is somehow inconvenient, as I have to store all requests until they are eventually handled in the receiving slot. There I have to remove them from the temporary list, as the receiving slot needs to destroy the request.

Comment: Actually, now that I look at the documentation, deleting the `QNetworkAccessManager` destroys all of its pending `QNetworkReply` instances, which in turn is supposed to close all their connections.  So simply deleting the `QNetworkAccessManager` should be OK.  I don't know why you're seeing an access violation -- it might be unrelated.

Comment: Could be, will re-read the documentation, thanks for the info. Strange that it only happens when I have a pending request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is that our `QNetworkAccessManager` is used in a threaded worker (1). So obviously when the `QNetworkAccessManager` is deleted, and in this step (and only then) cleans up pending `QNetworkReply` objects, the problem arises.

Analysis:
With no pending replies, or when used in the main thread, there is no issue in the same scenario. The issue can be avoided if the `QNetworkAccessManager` is deleted just before it is moved back to the main thread. Conclusion (or speculation): The issue occurs when the `QNetworkAccessManager` tries to delete a `QNetworkReply` created in a different thread.

(1) It is understood that requests are performed asynchronously - we have good design reasons for the threaded worker.