# How to dispatch replies from one QNetworkAccessManager?

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

[Qt documentation says](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details) that one `QNetworkAccessManager` is to be used per application:

> One QNetworkAccessManager should be enough for the whole Qt
>   application.

However, I access multiple web services and need to call individual functions for parsing each of those:

As I have only **one** `QNetworkAccessManager::finished(QNetworkReply * reply)` signal, what is the best way to dispatch the replies to its individual parsing function?

I could connect to the `finished` signal of each `QNetworkReply` object when I create the request:

```
QNetworkReply * QNetworkAccessManager::get(const QNetworkRequest & request)
```

But is it the best way to connect to a signal which only will be used once (performance)? Are there better ways?

---

Related own questions:

1. [Best way to share cookies within Qt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466168/best-way-to-share-cookies-within-qt-application)
2. [What is the correct way to "stop / shutdown" a QNetworkAccessManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906235/what-is-the-correct-way-to-stop-shutdown-a-qnetworkaccessmanager)
3. [QNetworkAccessManager get/post from different thread possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35684123/356726)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`QNetworkRequest::setOriginatingObject(QObject * object)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qnetworkrequest.html#setOriginatingObject) method in order to attach a reference of the originating object to the request.

Suppose we have two objects issuing network requests. In this case, you can use the following code to distinguish replies from each other.

```
QNetworkRequest *req1 = new QNetworkRequest();
req1->setOriginatingObject(sender1);
networkAccessManager->get(req1);

QNetworkRequest *req2 = new QNetworkRequest();
req2->setOriginatingObject(sender2);
networkAccessManager->get(req2);
```

And in your slot:

```
if(reply->request().originatingObject() == sender1){
     sender1->handle(...);
}

if(reply->request().originatingObject() == sender2){
     sender2->handle(...);
}
```

Comment: The originating object could implement an interface (in you case handle) and then even the if could go. Good idea with setOriginatingObject